# How to pass a hash tag (#) with an address bar variable ?searchTerm=#JustKeepGoing

Tags: php, url

How can I pass a variable that contains a hash tag via a website URL?
I currently pass this information into the URL, but cannot echo it out on the new page because '#' is used to anchor/jump to a specific page area.

Can I tell it to ignore the hash tag and echo what follows it?

**Current url:**

```
http://localhost/social3/search/?searchTerm=#JustKeepGoing
```

**Current way to echo content:**

```
$searchTerm = $_GET["searchTerm"];
echo $searchTerm;
```

Comment: it's not important to echo it out, but i need to content that follows it. Can i use to javascript or something to ignore the first character and output what follows?

Comment: long answer you can with js, as anything past the # never gets to the server, but js\ajax you can send it to the server

Comment: @AmalMurali: Nonsense, you just have to URL-encode it properly (as with _any_ parameter value).

Comment: @CBroe: I was a bit too quick. I thought the OP was asking how to pass values like: `example.com/page.html#stuff`. Removed my erroneous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to url encode it :

http://host.com/social3/search/?searchTerm=%23JustKeepGoing

Not sure your browser won't interpret it, but worth trying.